# Generic styles for numeric values in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I want to display all negative numbers(in xamdatagrid) in red color for which I don't want to assign the style  field by field rather style should be applied to all numeric columns.Is there any generic way to write the style.

So for ex : generally we  do

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}" x:key = "MyFieldStyle">     
    blah   
 </Style>

 ...
 <field Name = field1 cellstyle= MyFieldStyle/> 
 <field style= MyFieldStyle/> 

 ...
```

So instead of applying field by field can I write something to be applied on all numeric columns?

Comment: What grid are you using? Try using DataTemplateSelector in your default datatemplate to these fields http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: are you going to use any converter?

Comment: @pusp: I can use converter but there can be many numeric columns so how will I send each column's value?

Answer (score 1):

I attempted a solution using converter and style trigger

here is a sample

```
<DataGrid xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <l:SignConverter x:Key="SignConverter" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Numeric Value"
                            Binding="{Binding}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SignConverter}}"
                                     Value="-1">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="String Value"
                            Binding="{Binding SomeProperty,FallbackValue=String Value}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <sys:Double>-13</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double>13</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double>-1</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double>-3</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double>3</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double>0</sys:Double>
</DataGrid>
```

all you need to do is to apply the style on the relative columns, also you may need to update the trigger binding as necessary.

converter class

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class SignConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double outValue;
            if (value != null && double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out outValue))
                return Math.Sign(outValue);
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

result

[image: result]

---

**EDIT**

here is a workaround for the requested, in this approach you do not need to specifically set the style for individual columns

```
<DataGrid xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <l:SignConverter x:Key="SignConverter" />
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource SignConverter}}"
                             Value="-1">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Numeric Value"
                            Binding="{Binding [0]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="String Value"
                            Binding="{Binding [1]}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <x:ArrayExtension Type="{x:Type sys:Object}">
        <sys:Double>-13</sys:Double>
        <sys:String>hello</sys:String>
    </x:ArrayExtension>
    <x:ArrayExtension Type="{x:Type sys:Object}">
        <sys:Double>-1</sys:Double>
        <sys:String>hello 2</sys:String>
    </x:ArrayExtension>
    <x:ArrayExtension Type="{x:Type sys:Object}">
        <sys:Double>1</sys:Double>
        <sys:String>hello 3</sys:String>
    </x:ArrayExtension>
    <x:ArrayExtension Type="{x:Type sys:Object}">
        <sys:Double>0</sys:Double>
        <sys:String>hello 4</sys:String>
    </x:ArrayExtension>
</DataGrid>
```

converter (effectively same as earlier)

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class SignConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string text = value as string;
            double outValue;
            if (text != null && double.TryParse(text, out outValue))
                return Math.Sign(outValue);
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

result

[image: result]

above approach will work based on the assumption that `DataGridTextColumn` is used for such numbers, it may not work for other type of columns or template columns if the `TextBlock` or `TextBox` is not the first visual of the template.

Comment: thanks for the solution.But thats what my whole point was I have 50 columns out of which 20+ are numeric and I don't wanted to apply the styles manually for each column like u used different style for "Numeric Value" field. or even mention styles for each property .

Comment: the issue would be specifying the binding, in that case we can try other way, let me try the workaround